# Reference request for quenched disorder in stat mech

Tags: reference-request, recreational-mathematics, statistical-mechanics

I asked a similar question for references on rigorous results in statistical mechanics [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3509372/reference-request-for-gibbs-measure). One thing that I noticed is that the references people mentioned didn't quite cover the effect of quenched disorder on classical spin systems (e.g., discrete (Ising) models and continuous $O(N)$-models). I feel like adding quenched disorder is essential to modeling physical systems, so I was wondering if there are good references that cover such topics in a rigorous manner.

Comment: There is [this book](https://www.cambridge.org/ch/academic/subjects/statistics-probability/probability-theory-and-stochastic-processes/statistical-mechanics-disordered-systems-mathematical-perspective?format=HB&isbn=9780521849913) by Anton Bovier. For disordered mean-field models, you also have [this book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-15202-3) and [its sequel](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-22253-5) by Michel Talagrand and [this book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4614-6289-7) by Dmitry Panchenko.

Comment: @YvanVelenik Loved your book, Stat Mech of Lattice Systems.

Comment: I am happy to hear that. :) Thanks!